# Rails app + Apache Passenger + Postgres : CPU consumption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, cpu, rails-postgresql

I've a Rails 3.0 application that have a problem with the CPU consumption.

The application works in production mode on Apache + passenger mod on a Debian machine. It's a virtual machine with 6 Gb RAM and 2 CPU (1 core 3GHz). It's a mailing application and a simple click on a link to read a mail  requires a series of operations on the server to render the page. This simple click needs about 50% of CPU during 2 or 3 seconds (I see it with "top" command).

The problem is that I've about 150 users on the system and the Postgresql database is installed on the same machine. When several users make operations at same time, CPU is 100% used and Postgresql have enough resources to accept requests.

Is there any configuration that I can make (Apache? Passenger? Rails?) to prevent CPU increasing and Postgresql crash? Can I allocate jobs on two CPUs (I don't know if it's already the case)?

Thank you in advance.

Rémi

EDIT :

It seems that ruby processes allocate memory for jobs. But when the job is finished, the allocated memory seems to not be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Does postgreSQL actually *crash* ? that would be very strange; I'd expect it to be very slow, but not to crash. You may have other problems ...

You should be able to increase the priority of the postgresql daemon, or decrease the one of the rails app :) in Unix/Linux, nice (as root) should let you increase the priority of the postgresql server (so that it gets the CPU it needs, not the rails app).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that memory used increse too with the CPU.

In my Rails log, I've error like :

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: FATAL: arrêt des connexions suite à la demande de l'administrateur FATAL: arrêt des connexions suite à la demande de l'administrateur

SignalException (SIGTERM)

So the requests (select, insert,...) are refused by Postgresql. 
The log of Postgresql is empty during the problem (I suppose because Postgresql can't write to logs if it haven't resources to do it).

Answer (score 0):

From what you say your best option is probably to use a connection pooler and drop the number of simultaneous connections as much as you can.  This will lead to less PostgreSQL memory, but more importantly it will lead to better throughput because of less waiting on semaphores and disk I/O.  After all, there is only so much your processors and hard drives can do at once.  A good place to start is twice your CPU cores plus your number of disk spindles

On the Ruby side, that sounds like a garbage collection problem.  It is hard to say without a lot more info, but I would start out by dropping your number of simultaneous PostgreSQL connections since this is a web app and so connections are not likely to be idle for long.